# Why isn't this if statement returning the boolean value?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to make a program that will show if an input is a perfect number meaning the factors (not including the number) add up to be the same as that number. 
I got it working other than the return value. 
I want to return true if the sum of the factors is equal to the number entered however it just won't do it.

I have tried moving the if statement all over the code and it doesn't work anywhere.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    isPerfectNumber(28);
}

public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int number) {
    if (number < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    int numberToTest = 1;
    int sumOfFactors = 0;

    while (numberToTest < number) {
        if (number % numberToTest == 0) {
            sumOfFactors += numberToTest;
        }
        numberToTest++;
    }

    if (sumOfFactors == number) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I expect that when the code see that the sumOfFactors will have the sum = to the number entered and that's when I get the true statement however when that happens it doesn't return​ true. In fact, it doesn't return anything and states that the method returns were not used.

Comment: Can you please paste the entire function in the question?

Comment: And how you're calling it.

Comment: The entire function has been put into place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It "isn't working" because you aren't printing the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    isPerfectNumber(28);
}
```

should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPerfectNumber(28));
}
```

which is "true". Also,

```
if (sumOfFactors == number) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

is a long way to write

```
return sumOfFactors == number;
```

And, if you're using Java 8+, your `isPerfectNumber` method can be written as a one-liner with an `IntStream` and a lambda filter like

```
public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int number) {
    return number >= 1 && IntStream //
            .range(1, number) //
            .filter(i -> number % i == 0) //
            .sum() == number;
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed this I am sorry I am still in my first week with coding just a silly mistake. Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: Written as a *one*-liner with *four* lines of code? ;-) --- Also, are those `//` there for a reason?

Comment: @Andreas I think he's referring to the fact it's a single statement in Java, only one semicolon needed.

Comment: @penguin359 I know, but single *statement* and single *line* is not the same thing. `a = 1; b = 2;` can be a one-liner, even though it's two statements. And a huge 30-line stream method chain is a single statement, but hardly a one-liner.

Comment: It's a single line statement that I've broken up here for readability; The fact that I used comments to break the line is largely an [artifact of my IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221048/2970947).